# t.onAdd is not a function in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am using Leaflet draw to let users draw polygons and polylines and then I am computing the area of the polygon and the length of the polyline and displaying them in a popup.

When I try to complete the polygon by clicking the last point, I am not able to and I see this exception in the console:

> TypeError: t.onAdd is not a function

On the other hand when I complete the polyline, it runs fine the first time and I can see the popup with the length but when I draw it the second time, I cannot complete the polyline either and it shows me this exception in the console:

> TypeError: t.off is not a function

This is my code:

```
loadScript('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-draw/v0.2.2/leaflet.draw.js', function(){
    loadScript('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-geodesy/v0.1.0/leaflet-geodesy.js', function(){
        var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

        var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        edit: {
            featureGroup: featureGroup
        },
        draw: {
            polygon: true,
            polyline: true,
            rectangle: false,
            circle: false,
            marker: false
        }
    }).addTo(map);

    map.on('draw:created', showPolygonArea);
    map.on('draw:edited', showPolygonAreaEdited);

    function showPolygonAreaEdited(e) {
        e.layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            showPolygonArea({ layer: layer });
        });
    }
    function showPolygonArea(e) {
        var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

        if (type === 'polygon') {
            featureGroup.clearLayers();
            featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer.getLatLngs);
            e.layer.bindPopup(((LGeo.area(e.layer) / 1000000) * 0.62137).toFixed(2) + ' mi<sup>2</sup>');
            e.layer.openPopup();
        }

        if (type === 'polyline') {
            featureGroup.clearLayers();
            featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);

            // Calculating the distance of the polyline
            var tempLatLng = null;
            var totalDistance = 0.00000;
            $.each(e.layer._latlngs, function(i, latlng){
                if(tempLatLng == null){
                    tempLatLng = latlng;
                    return;
                }

                totalDistance += tempLatLng.distanceTo(latlng);
                tempLatLng = latlng;
            });
            e.layer.bindPopup((totalDistance).toFixed(2) + ' meters');
            e.layer.openPopup();
        }

    }
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you ever resolve your issue?

Comment: This was more than an year ago. Unfortunately I don't remember but I usually post answers if I find solutions so I think not. Looking back an year, it probably must have been some small mistake somewhere. I was very inexperienced back then and learning a lot of stuff at once. I still am. :)